# URL regex does not work in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I am trying to use [John Gruber's URL regex](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) in Javascript but NetBeans keeps telling me there is a syntax error and illegal errors:

```
 var patt = "/(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])
|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]
{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|
(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|
(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:
'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/";
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I think you need to also provide information on what the expression is supposed to do (mean) that way it's easier to check.

Comment: @Issun: It's this pattern: http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

Comment: This regex does not work for sites which does not start with www

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As others have said, it's the double quote. But alternatively, you can just write the regexp as a literal in javascript (but then you need to escape the forward slashes in lines 1 and 3 instead).

```
var regexp = /\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/i;
```

I also moved the case-insensitive modifier to the end. Just because. (edit: Well, not just "because" - see Alan Moore's comment below)

Note: Whether you use a literal or a string, **it has to be on 1 line.**

Comment: +1 for moving the `i` modifier to the end.  JavaScript does not support the inline-modifier syntax (`(?i)`) that Gruber used.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Heh, I didn't actually think about that when I wrote it. I just moved it to the end, because it's javascript, so that's "where it belongs, darn it!". Of course, you're right that that's the reason, but I just did it as a reflex :)

Answer (score 0):

put the whole expression in one line, and remove the quotes at the start and end so it looks like this `var patt = /the-long-patttern/;`, netbeans will still complain, but the browsers won't and thats what matters.

Answer (score 0):

You should write it like this in NetBeans:

```
      "(?i)\\b((?:[a-z][\\w-]+:(?:\\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]"
      + "+[.][a-z]{2,4}\\/)(?:[^\\s()<>]+|\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\))"
      + "+(?:\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\)|[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))";
```