# AngularJS ng-pattern website pattern

Tags: angularjs, regex

```
/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,7})$/
```

That's the pattern. It says "ok" when it's correct, and "not ok" when it's incorrect. So it says "ok" on www.google.com, but "not ok" when I type http://www.google.com

What I'd like is this pattern to allow http:// too, but it should never be a requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL regex does not work in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927719/url-regex-does-not-work-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression, which I <strike>lifted off</strike> borrowed from the documentation of the [Perl module URI on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI#PARSING-URIs-WITH-REGEXP) (escaping of slashes mine).

```
/(?:([^:\/?#]+):)?(?:\/\/([^\/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?/
```

It will give you all the different parts of the URI in capture groups.

Those parts are:

- scheme (*http:*)
- authority (not applicable here)
- path (*www.google.com*)
- query (*q=querystring*)
- fragment (*#anker*)

See https://regex101.com/r/vS5qO1/1 to try it out.

Also note that this will parse all types of URIs, not only http(s). So stuff like ftp://anonymous@example.org will also work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to *only* allow http/https URL schemes (when the scheme is provided), the following modification to your regular expression will do the trick:

`/^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,7})$/`

You can use my answer as an example of how to add the url scheme group to your existing regex, but credit @simbabque, as he has a much more complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @simbabque . I didn't want to make any gender assumptions when all your profile pic shows is the top of your head, lol!

Comment: Yes, I agree. I usually use [_they_ and _them_](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262119/the-use-of-gender-specific-pronouns-on-stack-overflow/262549).